# jQuery JSON post to a Sinatra route not working correctly

Tags: ajax, json, sinatra

I have a Sinatra route that looks like this:

```
post '/participants/create' do
  puts request.body.read
end
```

And I'm hitting it using a jQuery POST:

```
javascript:
  $('#contact').on('submit',function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'participants/create',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      type: 'POST',
      data : JSON.stringify({ name: "Dom"}),
      success: function(json) {
        alert('all done');
      }
    })
  })
```

For whatever reason the body is always empty, and the request.content-type is always `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Very confused.

Comment: Did you prevent the form from submitting?

Comment: Hmmmmm... good question. I need to use preventDefaults don't I?

Comment: Try `p params` in the body of your handler. Sinatra does some weird param handling sometimes.

Comment: Dominic, try `function(event) {`… `event.preventDefault()`. Also, Sinatra is nice enough to put the POST data into the `params` object/helper for you, no need to read the request body. Have a look at [jquery-json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) too, I've heard good things about it. Finally, try responding with `halt 200, params.inspect` instead of `puts `….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot a bit because I was trying to cram everything into the comments so I'll just answer.

```
post '/participants/create', :provides => :json do
  # I'd use a 201 as the status if actually creating something,
  # 200 while testing.
  # I'd send the JSON back as a confirmation too, hence the
  # :provides => :json
  data = JSON.parse params
  # do something with the data, then…
  halt 200, data.to_json
  # halt because there's no need to render anything
  # and it's convenient for setting the status too
end


javascript:
  $('#contact').on('submit',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'participants/create',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      type: 'POST',
      data : JSON.stringify({ name: "Dom"}),
      accepts: "application/json",
      success: function(json) {
        alert(json);
      }
    })
  })
```

Overall though, why send JSON to an HTTP server? I find it always works best to send HTTP to the server, JSON to the javascript, as that's what they both like better. YMMV.

```
post '/participants/create', :provides => :json do
  # Do something with the params, then…
  halt 200, params.to_json 
end

javascript:
  $('#contact').on('submit',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'participants/create',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data : { name: "Dom"}, // or $(event.target).serialize()
      accepts: "application/json",
      success: function(json) {
        alert(json);
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorted the issue, but good point about the JSON to HTTP server.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Glad to hear you got it sorted.

Comment: Hmm I am a little confused by the second answer. You're saying send HTTP to Sinatra, and send JSON to browser? Why not JSON to both? Also.. in both examples, params is empty, yet the request.body.read has the data.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra The question should be, why do you want to add an extra conversion step of parsing the data from JSON on the server? Sinatra (and other HTTP application server/frameworks) handle HTTP POST just fine without using JSON. Javascript, however, works well with JSON, [because it maps nicely to its object model](http://www.json.org/js.html) and there's a lot of support for it in libraries. I got it to work, here's a repo to look at https://github.com/yb66/stackoverflow-q-17870680

Comment: In this instance, the #participants/create method needs to be able to accept input from many sources (not just a web form). Perhaps I should let it respond to both HTTP and JSON.